# SQLite iPhone get last insert id

Tags: iphone, sqlite

[After inserting a record in SQLite]
I want to get last inserted id but i can't,what will i do?

Comment: You will not get the last inserted id

Comment: You could try posting a question on Stack Overflow with enough information to allow it to be answered...

Comment: Think you might want to give us a little more to go on. Please edit the question with some details of what you are trying to achieve and what you have tried already. Example code goes a long way. Read: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: i am inserting student record in sqlite and id is autoincreament...

Comment: You guys are harsh.

Comment: @user575620 Question edited before you get 5 votes, but you still need to click [edit] and give more info. What have you tried, where's your code stuck at?

Comment: @Matt @Simon @Jon Rather than making snide unhelpful comments, you might want to point people at useful resources such as Jon Skeet's [Writing the perfect question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) blog post. Also bear in mind that we were all beginners once and that English isn't everyone's native language.

Comment: @middaparka: Yeah..Sorry for that. Everyone will agree with you.. But note that, this is his 17th question.

Comment: @Simon True and a lot of them are inarguably poor, but it's pretty easy to keep a text file of generic "You need to improve your question, why not try..." style snippets.

Comment: dear friends@ next time i will ask question with complete detail.This time,i am sorry....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I presume you're talking about using SQLite (as it's about the only context your question makes any form of sense in), in which case you can simply use the [sqlite3_last_insert_rowid](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html) function.

If this isn't the case, you need to re-word your question to provide some additional information.

Comment: thax middaparka @its working Id = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database);